# Problems while splitting in two columns with big title?

Tags: sectioning, titles, paragraphs, cv

I am designing from the scratch my own CV template. I would like to split the text in two columns like this:

[image]

So far I tried to do it by:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 13pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=0.4in,footskip= 3 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\date{\vspace{0ex}}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}



\setlength{\droptitle}{-4.5em}   % con esto se mueve el titulo



\title{\textbf{{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont John Doe}}}




\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\maketitle
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

However, its not working. Since I got this output:

[image]

How can remove the text from the title space, and split it into 2 columns?

Comment: Just put the `\maketitle` command *before* entering the `multicols` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `\maketitle` before `multicol`.

See the following MWE (see that I moved `hyperref` to be the last called package):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 13pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=0.4in,footskip= 3 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\date{\vspace{0ex}}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-4.5em}   % con esto se mueve el titulo
\title{\textbf{{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont John Doe}}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle % <==========================================================
\begin{multicols}{2}

%\maketitle % <=========================================================
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

To get the name starting on the left you need to delete the centering in command `\@maketitle`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
% \begin{center}% <=====================================================
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
% \end{center}% <=======================================================
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
```

Add this code to the preamble (`\makeatother` and `\makeatletter` are need for the `@` in commands):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 13pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=0.4in,footskip= 3 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\date{\vspace{0ex}}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-4.5em}   % con esto se mueve el titulo
\title{\textbf{{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont John Doe John Doe John Doe}}}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
% \begin{center}% <=====================================================
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
% \end{center}% <=======================================================
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\maketitle % <==========================================================
\begin{multicols}{2}

%\maketitle % <=========================================================
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting title]